# Python functional programming, scope and variable. Where am I going wrong?

Tags: python, list, loops, opencv, scope

I am assembling a list of class functions from graphical item selections, at the end of the chain, I pass the function list to a loop for processing. All fine there. Except the loop doesn't seem to accumulate but only applies whatever the last class function applied was. I think this is due to scope but was wondering if some experienced guru can point me in the right direction.

Here is a code snippet without the loop that works as expected. There are just two functions for clarity:

```
frame=cv2.GaussianBlur(frame,(15,15),0) and frame=cv2.flip(frame, 1)
```

The function setups an incoming video stream from video card or camera using `self.capture()` and then `frame = cv2.cvtColor()`, to provide an individual frame object that can be processed separately, in this instance the frames are blurred and flipped in orientation, using openCV (`cv2`) class functions, as expected, fine.

```
def display_video_stream(self):
    self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    frame = self.capture.read()
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    #want to replace these class functions with function list
    frame = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame,(15,15),0)
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)

    image = QImage(frame, frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0], 
                       frame.strides[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
    self.image_label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))
```

So, now I replace the two functions with a list that is processed within a for loop as below. However, when I do this, I don't get the same result. It's only the last operation in the function list applied. So instead of blurred then flipped, I get blurred or flipped, according to the order of the list. I checked the loop is looping with a print statement and that's fine, the index numbers are looping over in the console fine as the video source streams, so it is processing the functions OK but whereas the first example accumulates the frame output by passing the result of the first operation as the new source value for the second operation, the loop version doesn't.

I think this is scope within the loop. So where I specify the frame value as:

```
frame = self.capture.read()
```

Before entering the loop, it seems either the loop internally is always holding onto that initial value of frame and not accumulating it along the function list, while processing, or just over writing the frame value fresh, each time, inside the loop. I don't get it! The two snippets should be equal in operation, in my mind. So how do I handle the scope here, if indeed it is a scope issue. I'm stumped.

```
def display_video_stream(self):
    self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    frame = self.capture.read()
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    #this loop works but seems to only return last frame function, not  accumulate. As if loop overwrites frame each time.
    #with original value or perhaps is out of scope and reverts to self.setup_frame() value eachtime?
    #whichever is last function in list, that is the result returned in output but not both.

    functions = [cv2.GaussianBlur(frame,(15,15),0), cv2.flip(frame, 1)]
    indexval = 0
    for i in range(len(functions)):
        frame = functions[indexval]
        indexval += 1

    image = QImage(frame, frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0], 
                       frame.strides[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
    self.image_label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))
```

Comment: Fist, format you code; second add `opencv` tag; third give a short brief description.

Comment: I don't really see any functional programming going on. I've tried to fix the indentation, please verify that this now reflects your actual code. If it does, then the issue is rather obvious, your loop sets `frame` repeatedly and only the last assigned value is used after the loop to pass to `QImage`.

Comment: Why the separate `indexval`? You already have `i` from your `for` loop. And you could just use `for frame in functions:` and drop the `indexval` or `i` indices altogether.

Comment: Ok, that's pretty much what I said. So how do you fix that?

Comment: I tried different methods of loop, including ennumerate, the result is always the same. How to update the frame value so the loop and non-loop are identical in operation?

Comment: loop method isn't the issue to focus here. Frame variable is. Sorry, just trying to keep on track with the question. Thanks.

Comment: Your code is more of an idiomatic example of what functional programming is not. Why do you bring it up in your title?

Comment: Do you have an example of why example one works and example 2 doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. your usage of read was wrong.

```
ret, frame = cap.read()
```

Document on it:

```
read(...) method of cv2.VideoCapture instance
    read([, image]) -> retval, image
    .   @brief Grabs, decodes and returns the next video frame.
    .
    .   @param [out] image the video frame is returned here. If no frames has b$
    .   @return `false` if no frames has been grabbed
    .   ....
```

> 2. your `functions` variable is not functions, but a list of processed images.

```
functions = [
    lambda frame:cv2.GaussianBlur(frame,(15,15),0),
    lambda frame: cv2.flip(frame, 1)
]


for func in functions:
    frame = func(frame)
```

> 3. maybe the way you change frame to QImage is not right, I'm not really sure.

[image]

Comment: This is a code snippet. I have used ret, frame = cap.read() in the write function, which is pure openCV, in a while loop, using the same function list. Same result. Example 1 works (using PySide as windowing, not openCV, doesn't need ret, frame). Again WHY does example 1 WORK and example 2 doesn't?

Comment: OK, point 2 seems like the kind of answer I was thinking. I'll give it a go. I don't think the intermediate PySide conversion will be an issue since version one, without loop, works and displays. That's all the question is. Make version two do what version one does. Thanks.

Comment: It'll be a few hours till I get back to computer to test, hopefully this works and I'll mark the question answered. Fingers crossed, this has been driving me nutty for a few days. Thanks.